# Android emulator unable to connect to local server (No input file specified)

Tags: android, apache, xampp

I am running XAMPP on my windows machine and trying to connect to it using "http://10.0.2.2" through stock browser on android emulator.

It used to work fine in the past but I am getting strange error today ***"No input file specified"***
This same error comes whether I try to access a html page or php script.

I have tried different emulators and tried restarting my XAMPP.

I also tried turning off my windows firewall just in case it might block but to no effect.

Android emulator is able to access other sites like google.com without any error.
Accessing local server through desktop browser also works ok.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay....... So, there is this really COOL 2 MB php IDE http://sourceforge.net/projects/devphp/files/

When you run it, and then run any webserver, you will not be able to connect to server.

I tried different servers, wamp, abyss and nothing was working. Just closing down this IDE corrected all problems, problems resurfaced when IDE was started again. Yuckk! 6 hrs or so.

Weird stuff!

If anyone can explain why, I will mark that as answer.